# An interesting integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(x+2)^a}$ for $a>0$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to know how to solve this integral. For $a>0$,
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+1)(x+2)^a}$$
I tried the substitution $1-u=x+2$, in the hope that I could put the integral in terms of the incomplete Beta function:
$$I(a)=-\int_{-\infty}^{-1}\frac{du}{u(1-u)^a}$$
Which didn't really work out, because the bounds are all wrong.

I do not know how to proceed. Please help

Comment: And why do you assume this is evaluatable in a non-numerical way?

Comment: For integer $a$, consider partial fractions?

Comment: @RushabhMehta I thought there might be certain substitutions which could put the integral in terms of a special function

Comment: @gt6989b That's the way the Symbolab Integral Calculator does it... But I wanted to find a more general form if it existed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By writing $\frac{1}{(x+1)}$ as $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{(x+2)^n}$ we have that the original integral equals

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(x+2)^{n+a}} = \sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{2^{a+m}(a+m)}$$
i.e. a value of the [Lerch trascendent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lerch_zeta_function), namely $2^{-a}\,\Phi\left(\frac{1}{2},1,a\right)$.

Comment: That's really clever, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\vphantom{\large A}\mrm{I}\pars{a}\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{a}\ >\ 0} & \equiv \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x + 1}\pars{x + 2}^{a}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{x + 1\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-1}\pars{1 + x}^{-a}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{1}x^{a - 1}\,\pars{1 - x}^{0}\,\pars{1 + x}^{-a}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\,\mrm{B}\pars{a,4}
{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}\pars{a,a;a + 1;-1}}
\\[2mm] & \mbox{where}\quad
\pars{\begin{array}{l}
\mrm{B}:\ Beta\ Function
\\
{}_{2}\mrm{F}_{1}:\ Hypergeometric\ Function
\end{array}}
\end{align}
See [Euler Type Hypergeometric Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Euler_type).

Comment: Nice answer! Are there any identities with $\Gamma(s)$ that you can simplify that hypergeometric to? I know we can get $$B(a,4)=\frac{24\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a+4)}$$ How else can we simplify the answer?

Comment: @clathratus Maybe. It's possible but Hypergeometric Function has a lot of identities.